# Laravel whereDate not working

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I want to load more links of day, but the whereDate not working, and I don't know why... The date format is correct.

```
public function day_load_more($clicks, $total_links, $data) {

    $data_carbon = Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y h:i:s', '20-02-2018 00:00:00');
    $ex_link_in = explode(',', $_POST['links_inserts']);

                    $links = Link::where('status', '=', 1)
                    ->WhereNotIn('id', $ex_link_in)
                    ->whereDate('created_at', $data_carbon)
                    ->where('clicks', '<=', $clicks)
                    ->orderBy('clicks', 'desc')
                    ->with('page', 'tag')
                    ->where('sponsored', 0)
                    ->take(10)
                    ->get();
}
```

The stranger thing, is that in the other method works fine (show only links of day):

```
    public function linksofday($data){
        $data_carbon = Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y h:i:s', '20-02-2018 00:00:00');

        $links = Link::where('status', '=', 1)
        ->orderBy('clicks', 'desc')
        ->with('page', 'tag')
        ->where('sponsored', 0)
        ->whereDate('created_at', $data_carbon)
        ->whereNotIn('id', [$this->getFirstLinkDay($data)->id])
        ->take(10)
        ->get();
}
```

I got 5 links of day 20-02, when I roll the page, should not show anything more, but shows links of others days...

Comment: Did you try to change the date format from 'd-m-Y h:i:s' to 'Y-m-d h:i:s' .

Comment: Not working, the error is not this, because in the other method "linksofday" works fine...

Comment: What exactly is the error?

Comment: The load more shows links of other day, the wheredate not working, it's like I have not placed the wheredate...

Comment: Have you tried `->whereDate('created_at', $data_carbon->toDateString())` ?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the issue is with your parsing of the `date` but rather with some other `where` or maybe because some of the input variable has wrong data, also instead of using `$_POST` you can just access it's data with `Request` object

Comment: Note: Function names are case-insensitive, though it is usually good form to call functions as they appear in their declaration. http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php, why does it make a difference here?

Comment: I don't think there is an issue with your `date` parsing, but rather with some other `where` clause, check all the input parameters, and btw why are u using `$_POST` when you have the access to `Request` object? I'll edit my answer @ShobiPP thanks for pointing it out